# z-index not working with position relative

Tags: html, css

I write css coded is the following lines. but not working `z-index`.

I want to know how I can make the `z-index` work while keeping the value of `position` as `relative`.

```css
      #foo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: lightblue;
      }

      #bar {
        width: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: lightpink;
      }
```

As far as I know, if you set the value of `position` to a non-static value, the `z-index` should work. Are there any other factors that affect the `z-index`?

Also if I change the value of `position` to `absolute` it works fine.

##### When `position` is `relative`

[image]

##### When `position` is `absolute`

[image]

Comment: when using relative position, The element will remain in the natural flow of the page. It also makes the element positioned. it will act as an anchor point for the child elemnts.
you can read more here : https://cssreference.io/positioning/

Comment: What's the actual goal and *how* isn't it working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- everything is working as you need you can see I have added `margin-bottom:-20px;` to `.foo` so that you can se that in effect that `.foo` is behind `.bar`.
- Understand that position won't take item out of flow, which will keep it at it's position. **To see this in effect there must be some overlapping between two elements, than you can see the `z-index` in efffect.**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#foo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

#bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
```